# Display table on flex item

Tags: css, flexbox

My question is simple. Is it possible to have display: table on a flex item?

When I set it on an item, the layout doesn't work as expected - the second flex item doesn't grab the available vertical/horizontal space.

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  background-color: gray;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: table;
  background-color: red;
}

.content > span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header">
    <span>Header</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span>Main content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really sure if i understand your question, but is [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/f4bL382b/) what you are looking for

Comment: @DavidDomain no, the 'Main content' span is not centered in vertical direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, but not necessarily a good solution though.

May I suggest you use `flex` all the way.

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  background-color: gray;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header">
    <span>Header</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span>Main content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Side note:

A `table` element is special and doesn't behave as normal block or inline elements. To make it work with `display: table`, you need to set a height to your parent as well as to the `table`, like in this sample, http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/0bzewkf4.

Still, as you can see, the `table` height is 200px because `flex` has some flaws when it comes to limit height's, so it is not `display:table` that breaks your `flex`, it is `flex` who is somewhat broken.

Here is another answer of mine, showing yet another workaround where `flex` doesn't behave: [Normalizing Flexbox overflow in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920485/normalizing-flexbox-overflow-in-ie11/35923853#35923853)

Comment: This is great and I use that. But I can't use display table as you can see in my question. And my question is WHY? Why it brokes the flexbox layout?

Comment: @Behnil A table element is special and doesn't behave as normal block or inline elements. To make it work with `display: table`, you need to set a height to  your parent as well as to the table ... will post a sample soon.

Comment: @Behnil Here is sample that works, kind of, https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/0bzewkf4/, though still, as you can see, the table height is 200px because `flex` has some flaws when it comes to limit height's. Here is another answer of mine, showing yet another workaround when `flex` doesn't behave: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920485/normalizing-flexbox-overflow-in-ie11/35923853#35923853

Comment: @Behnil I updated my answer, a side note, with my comments, which hopefully give you an answer to your question, and as you can see, it is not `display:table` that breaks your `flex`, it is `flex` who is somewhat broken

Answer (score 0):

Tables are row or horizontally oriented so wouldn't you get weird results if placed within a flex-column? I changed everything to a good old block, they stack very well in a column flow--vertical harmony.

`.content` is dead center by using: `position: relative;` `top: 50%;` and `translateY(360%);` for vertical and `text-align: center;` for horizontal. Oh and of course turning that span into a useful block.

Changed the following:

```
.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
.content > span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(360%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

<del>I changed `display: table` to `table-row` is this what you wanted?</del>

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
.header {
  background-color: gray;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
.content > span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(360%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header">
    <span>Header</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span>Main content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I need the red div to grab all available space and the 'Main content' span to be centered in both direction.

Comment: What do you mean all available space? It is taking what's left of `.parent`

Answer (score 0):

It's a big question why  you use table in flexbox...
But you can set width to your table and inherit min-height from parent

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  background-color: gray;
}

.content {
  display: table;
  flex:1;
  background-color: red;
  width:100%;

min-height:inherit; 
}

.content > span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header">
    <span>Header</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span>Main content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to use a table layout at all here. Just add `align-self: center;` to `.content- > span {...`. And make the `span` element become a flex item as well, by adding `display:flex` to the `.content` element. The reason why the table layout is not working for you is because `vertcal-align` has no effect on the alignment of flex items. So mixing a flex-layout with a table-layout by changing the display property of a flex-item seems not to be a good idea, because you are loosing the flexibility of the flex-layout.

> [Properties not affecting flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Flexible_box_properties)
>
> Because flexible boxes use a different layout algorithm, some properties do not make sense on a flex container:
>
> **column-*** properties of the multiple column module have no effect on a flex item.
>   **float** and **clear** have no effect on a flex item. Using float causes the display property of the element to compute to block.
>   **vertical-align** has no effect on the alignment of flex items.

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  background-color: gray;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.content > span {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header">
    <span>Header</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span>Main content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, the 'Main content' span is not centered in vertical direction, take a look at `vertical-align: middle;` in my question.

Comment: Was not sure if that is what you wanted. I have made an edit. You basically just have to make the `span` become a flex item as well, by adding `display: flex` to the `.content` element too.

Comment: Yes, the same solution as I get from @LGSon. But my question is not how to achieve the layout, but why the display: table breaks the flexbox layout.

Comment: Check the edit. There are properties which have no effect on flex items.